# No iptables.up.rules file

Tags: iptables

I am [following a tutorial](https://adilmehmoodbutt.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/how-to-install-squid3-transparent-proxy-server/) on setting up a transparent squid proxy on Ubuntu. The instructions state:

---

> Step 5. define IPTABLE rules for port forwarding with Editing `etc/iptables.up.rules`,

```
sudo nano /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

> Then add:

```
*nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.10:3128 -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128 -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE COMMIT
```

---

My Ubuntu box does not have an `etc/iptables.up.rules` file. Do I simply create one? Or is there an alternative location to this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I simply create one?

Yes.

By the way: in theory the file name and location do not really matter. It is important to store the file somewhere where you need admin permissions. '/etc/` is a good location for that.

Comment: Okay. But then how are they loaded in?

Comment: see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo "Configuration on startup"